# Google SDTT does not recognize "reservationNumber" and "airline"

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

There are two errors recognised:

1. The property `reservationNumber` is not recognised by Google for an
   object of type `FlightReservation`
2. The property `airline` is not recognised by Google for an object of type `Flight`.

[image: Google SDTT output, showing two errors]

Comment: What kind of help do you expect? Schema.org doesn’t seem to define a `reservationNumber` property nor an `airline` property.

Comment: @unor, Thank your support and also i used JSON-LD intend of MICRODATA..  then it works..

Comment: If it works in JSON-LD but not in Microdata, it should be a bug in Google’s SDTT. Can you include the working JSON-LD example (as code) in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are very clear.

1. Per [FlightReservation](https://schema.org/FlightReservation), you cannot use the reservationNumber property. There is **no such property ‘reservationNumber’ for *any* type** in schema.org.
2. **[Airline](https://schema.org/Airline) is a type**, not a property of [Flight](https://schema.org/Flight). There is no such property ‘airline’.

Comment: And yet, Googleʼs Email Markup Tester insists that reservationNumber is a required property.

Comment: @Brian "A few of the schema structures used by Gmail differ from the schema.org standard vocabulary." https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/schema-org-proposals